# php &variables in the URL aren't being defined in the page

Tags: php

I have a messages page that loads communications between two users. The URL is `message.php?u=[me]&p=[message parent id]&op=[other person]`, but `$p` and `$op` are not being defined in the page. When I echo each variable separately, `$u` appears everywhere from pre  tag to the bottom of the document, but `$p` and `$op` do not echo anywhere. I tried deleting everything in .htaccess to see if that was causing a bug, but it wasn't. I can't think of what would cause this.

Comment: `$_GET['p']`/`$_GET['op']` doesn't work as well?

Comment: Show the actual query string you're using, and the output of `print_r($_GET)`.

Comment: OP is presumably expecting register_globals and hasn't looked [at the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yourscript.php?var1=value1&var2=value2`

You can use this by:

```
$var1 = $_GET['var1']; // $var1 = 'value1'
$var2 = $_GET['var2']; // $var2 = 'value2'
```

You can check whether or not these URL-parameters are set with `isset()`
(otherwise you create errors when you do not set them):

```
if (isset($_GET['var1'])) {
    $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
} else {
    die('usage: yourscript.php?var1=value1 !');
}
```